# How to let different parts of yaml reference to one global field?

Tags: yaml

**1. BACKGROUND:**

I use yaml anchor to share piece of global fragment in yaml, like next:

**trial1.yaml:**

```
extra_environment:
  postgres_password: &passwd abc

newnew:
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: *passwd
  POSTGRES_CONNECT_STRING: *passwd
```

Then I will go to http://www.yamllint.com/ to lint this yaml, it will render this yaml as next:

```
---
extra_environment:
  postgres_password: abc
newnew:
  POSTGRES_CONNECT_STRING: abc
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: abc
```

You can see `*passwd` successfully be rendered as `abc`, perfect!

**2. MY PROBLEM:**

Then, I have another yaml here:

**trial2.yaml:**

```
extra_environment:
  postgres_password: &passwd abc

newnew:
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: *passwd
  POSTGRES_CONNECT_STRING: postgres://postgres:*passwd@db:5432/postgres
```

Go to http://www.yamllint.com/ again, it rendered to me as next:

```
--- 
extra_environment: 
  postgres_password: abc
newnew: 
  POSTGRES_CONNECT_STRING: "postgres://postgres:*passwd@db:5432/postgres"
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: abc
```

Looks it can't be rendered if there are things before/after `*`.

**My expected output:**

```
---
extra_environment:
  postgres_password: abc
newnew:
  POSTGRES_CONNECT_STRING: postgres://postgres:abc@db:5432/postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: abc
```

**3. QUESTION:**

For my scenario, if possible yaml could have any ways to handle this? Not limited to yaml anchor, others also ok for me.